# Continuous Integration vs Software automation test engineer

Tags: python, unit-testing, continuous-integration, functional-testing

I understand that we use CI to test a software after any changes made to it.It will kick off unit tests and system level tests as soon as someone checks-in.

Now, where unit and functional test scripts we wrote fit in here?
Am I right that CI won't have any built-in tests: unit,functional,system. "We" write all those test scripts but have CI kick them off ?

Comment: Continuous integration servers are very handy, but they aren't magic! Yes, you still need to write the test scripts; the CI server just runs them automatically (e.g. when you push to your central repo), it doesn't already know what you think your code is supposed to be doing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CI is intended to be a system which provides a framework for all your unit tests and functional tests. The CI will kick off the unit tests , build and run functional tests and take appropriate actions as specified by you.